# Prove there is a unique p such that the integral holds true

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I am looking at the following problem:

$[a,b]$ a closed interval in $R$ and $A$ and $K$ are continuous real-valued functions on $[a,b]$ and {$(x,y) \in E^2$: $a \leq y \leq x \leq b$} respectively. Prove that there is a unique $p \in C([a,b])$ such that $p(x) = A(x) + \int_{a}^{x} K(x,y)p(y)dy$ for all $x \in [a,b]$

I have already shown that if $|(b-a)K(x,y)| < 1$ for all $x,y$ $\in$ $[a,b]$ then F is a contraction map and therefore there is a unique $p \in C([a,b])$ such that $p(x) = A(x) + \int_{a}^{b} K(x,y)p(y)dy$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.

Note: $g \in C([a,b])$, and define $F(g) \in C([a,b])$ by $(F(g))(x) = A(x) + \int_{a}^{b} K(x,y)g(y)dy$

I am a little confused what to do now. It seems as there are a few cases that need to be handled such that we need to prove the existence of a unique $p_{1} \in C([a,b])$ such that  for all $x \in [a,a_{1}]$ and the existence of a unique $p_2\in C([a,b])$ such that $p_{2}(x) = A(x) + \int_{a}^{a_{1}} K(x,y)p_{1}(y)dy + \int_{a_{1}}^{x} K(x,y)p_{2}(y)dy$ for all $x \in [a_{1},b]$. I think this might work but am not sure how to show this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ finite?

Comment: Let $T\colon C([a,b]) \to C([a,b])$ be defined by $(Tf)(x) = \int_a^x K(x,y)f(y)\,dy$. Consider the iterates $T^2 = T\circ T, T^3, T^4,\dotsc$.